# C++ Trying to pass arrays to functions

Tags: c++

I am trying to make this code work on Visual Studio 2022, but it tells me that after the second `void printArray(int theArray\[\], int sizeOfArray)` it expected a `;`. I am doing this code based on https://youtu.be/VnZbghMhfOY. How can I fix this?

Here is the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printArray(int theArray[], int sizeOfArray);

int main()
{
    int bucky[3] = {20, 54, 675};
    int jessica[6] = {54, 24, 7, 8, 9, 99};

    printArray(bucky, 3);

    void printArray(int theArray[], int sizeOfArray)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeOfArray; x++){
            cout << theArray[x] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change the code order but that only made it worse, the error saying `;` is apparently useless and the whole thing breaks apart if I put it there.

Comment: better dont try to learn C++ from youtube videos. Try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: You simply cannot define functions like this inline in c++ code blocks. If that's a requirement for your solution, use a lambda expression and `std::function` instead. Voted to close as a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take the implementation of the function "printArray" out of the main.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printArray(int theArray[], int sizeOfArray);

int main()
{

    int bucky[3] = {20, 54, 675};
    int jessica[6] = {54, 24, 7, 8, 9, 99};

    printArray(bucky, 3);
    return 0;
}
void printArray(int theArray[], int sizeOfArray)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < sizeOfArray; x++){
        cout << theArray[x] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for the scalability: `3` +> `sizeof bucky`

Comment: @Sandburg [`sizeof bucky`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) != 3. It's the size of `bucky` in **bytes**, probably 12. [`std::size(bucky)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) == 3.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't have nested functions. You need:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printArray(int theArray[], int sizeOfArray);

int main()
{

    int bucky[3] = {20, 54, 675};
    int jessica[6] = {54, 24, 7, 8, 9, 99};

    printArray(bucky, 3);

}

void printArray(int theArray[], int sizeOfArray)
{

    for (int x = 0; x < sizeOfArray; x++)
    {
         cout << theArray[x] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Nested functions exist](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/M6resd9h3)